# Subset notation in Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis"

Tags: real-analysis, notation

I've just began reading Walter Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis". Early on in the text is introduced subset notation, with which I am familiar. My problem is that Rudin doesn't seem to differentiate between the notation for "is a subset of" ( $\subseteq$ ) and "is a proper subset of" ( $\subset$ ).

I'm still on chapter 1, but Rudin has thus far only used $\subset$, as in

"If A and B are sets, and if every element of A is an element of B, we say that A is a subset of B, and write A $\subset$ B [...]"

where Rudin defines "subset". Directly after that, Rudin defines "proper subset", but does not provide notation for it:

"If, in addition, there is an element of B which is not in A, then A is said to be a $proper$ subset of B."

It seems to me that differentiating between $\subseteq$ and $\subset$ is important.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Just like not everyone in the world speaks Mandarin Chinese. Not everyone uses the same notation.

Comment: Some authors use $\subset$ to mean $\subseteq$.  They can then use $\subsetneq$ to specify a proper subset.

Comment: @Jair I am familiar. Rudin doesn't do that.

Comment: Well, the first quote you gave would indicate it.  But I have not read Rudin myself so I cannot say.

Comment: in "almost all" mathematical books it is costumary to write $\subset$ for the same meaning that $\subseteq$. That is: if reading a book you find $\subset$ and it is not explicitly stated that this mean $\subsetneq$ then you must understand that it is the same meaning that $\subseteq$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rudin's book uses ⊂ to mean subset, which is not all that uncommon. The topic of Rudin's book is not set theory and the distinction between a subset and a proper subset is often unimportant in this text, so Rudin does not introduce notation for proper subset. If needed, something like "A ⊂ B proper" may be written to specify a proper subset with this notation.

Comment: One can also use $A\subsetneq B$ (the symbol is `\subsetneq`).