# Set Closure Theorem in Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis

Tags: analysis

In Rudin's book, there is a theorem about set closure:

> If $E\subset F$ and $F$ is closed $\Rightarrow$ $\bar E\subset F$ (the closure $\bar E=E\cup E^\prime$, $E^\prime$ is limit points of E).

Think of a scenario that $E$ contains all elements in $F$ except for the margin. In the graph, blue shaded closed set is $F$ and the $E$ is at the same scale but without the margin:

[image]

It satisfy the condition that $E\subset F$ and $F$ is closed, but $\bar E=F$, which implies *subset* instead of *proper subset*. Any explanation for it?

Comment: Where do you see *proper subset* here in Rudin's book? I think $A\subset B$ here means $A\subseteq B$. An easier example is $E=(0,1)$, the open interval, with $F=[0,1]$ the closed interval.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes, you are right. I also see some discussion about the notation in this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3229879/subset-notation-in-rudins-principles-of-mathematical-analysis. Thank you for your answer.